# How to make a translucent toolbar in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

How to make a translucent/transparent toolbar in android so that views behind that would be visible while scrolling up?
Whatever goes behind this toolbar it should reflect on it.

**Here is my toolbar XML code:**

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/back">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_back"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_10"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_10"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_left_icon" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/antum_logo_iv"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_22"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                style="@style/Font.Med16"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/sign_up"
                android:textColor="@color/aubergine" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/right_action"
                style="@style/Font.Reg16"
                android:text="@string/title_edit"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="@color/purple" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/right_action_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/margin_10" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Though if I am setting the toolbar theme with Theme. Transparent with removing `AppBarLayput` it gets a transparent theme but still, the views are not visible behind this.

Comment: Have a look at this https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/translucent-systembars-the-right-way-across-api-levels-and-themes-6d7ddda21396

Answer (score 1):

To have a transparent toolbar, you need to:

1. Set a full transparent `AppBarLayout` with 0 elevation.
2. Set a semi-transparent color to the Toolbar to make the content appear in the back.
3. Set a negative margin to the scrolling view, and reverse that on the child of that scrolling view (for `RecyclerView` do that for the 1st child view programmatically in the adapter's `onBindViewHolder()` by checking the position = 0), or using 2 separate layouts one for the 1st child with top margin, and the other without margin for other views.

Demo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#C9F1E8E7"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingStart="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Welcome!" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In case that the scrolling content is a `RecyclerView`, to reverse back the top margin:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val params = holder.itemView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
    params.topMargin =
        if (position == 0) {
            val resources: Resources = holder.itemView.context.resources
            val dip = 100f // top margin assumed as 100dp
            val px = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                dip,
                resources.displayMetrics
            )
            px.toInt()
        } else 0
        
    holder.itemView.layoutParams = params
    
    //.....
    
}
```

You can change the toolbar color to your favorite transparent color.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to modify you app theme or activity theme , modify from the color to transparent color like this `<item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>` and also do windowActionBarOverlay true.

```
 <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/my_text_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

> **Alternative solution**

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);   
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```